# How do I set up a Catalyst 2960 as a dumb switch?

Tags: cisco, switch

I am completely new to network management (I'm just a linux sysadmin, myself), and have no idea at all how to set up this thing.

It's not for a production environment, I'm just using it for my home network (as I got it as a gift and I gladly took it :P)

I've already got console access and everything (via telnet, e.g. `telnet 10.0.0.1` etc.)

Help, please?

Comment: If you want to use it as a dumb (unmanaged) switch, there is nothing you need to do. Unfortunately, questions about home networking are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: Yeah, just..use it.  Look up the procedure for a factory reset if you want to wipe whatever settings are currently configured.

Comment: Answer: *Power. It. On.* Unless it has someone else's configuration still on it, the default is all ports enabled in VLAN 1.

Comment: Just use it!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to do anything. If the switch has no config setup, all of its ports will be in VLAN1 and the device will act as a typical unmanaged switch.

If some config exists, then you need to reset it to the defaults or just check if all of the ports are in the same VLAN and if they are setup as an access ports.

Here's the guide on how to reset the switch to the defaults:
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-2900-xl-series-switches/24328-156.html

Regards!

Comment: Wow, didn't think that it would be so simple. Are most switches like this?

Comment: Well... Yeah, that's what they are for :) They just give you a number of additional options to suit your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off routing and create two Vlans.  Set vlan 1 to be untagged on which ever ports you want, and vlan2 untagged on the other ports.  The two vlans will stay seperate and the untagged directive means that whatever you plug into that port just goes to that vlan. 2960 switch is already pretty low on the IQ scale. Create the VLANs, disable trunking and put the ports in the VLAN you want them in. That's as simple as it gets.